# bash determine if variable is empty and if so exit.

Tags: bash, if-statement, md5

I am trying to perform this: 
i have a test file which md5sum of files located on sftp. 
variables should contain an md5sum (string), if the variable is empty it means there is no file on the sftp server. 
i am trying this code but it does not work..

```
    if [ -z $I_IDOCMD5 ] || [ -z $I_LEGALMD5 ] || [ -z $I_ZIPMD5 ]
then
        echo "ERROR: At least one file not present of checksum missing no files will be deleted" >>$IN_LOG
        ERRORS=$ERRORS+2
else
 if [[ $I_IDOCMD5 == $($DIGEST -a md5 $SAPFOLDER/inward/idoc/$I_IDOC) ]]
   then
        echo "rm IDOC/$I_IDOC" >/SAP/commands_sftp.in
   else
        echo "problem with checksum"
        ERRORS=$ERRORS+2
 fi

 if [[ $I_LEGALMD5 == $($DIGEST -a md5 $SAPFOLDER/inward/legal/$I_LEGAL) ]]
   then
        echo "rm LEGAL/$I_LEGAL" >>/SAP/commands_sftp.in
   else
        echo "problem with checksum"
        ERRORS=$ERRORS+2
 fi

 if [[ $I_ZIPMD5 == $($DIGEST -a md5 $SAPFOLDER/inward/zip/$I_ZIP) ]]
   then
        echo "rm ZIP/$I_ZIP" >>/SAP/commands_sftp.in
   else
        echo "problem with checksum"
        ERRORS=$ERRORS+2
fi
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_? what are you getting, and what are you expecting?

Comment: Enclose your variables in double quotes. Whitespace (or worse)  can be a dealbreaker if you don't.

Comment: It maybe not relevant, but check if there is a "fi" statement missing somewhere.

Comment: Hello,thank you.. i mean even if one variable is empty it will still do all the md5 verifications.. I want it to skip all the md5 verification if at least one variable is empty.

Answer (score 68):

The answer I prefer is following

```
[[ -z "$1" ]] && { echo "Parameter 1 is empty" ; exit 1; }
```

Note, don't forget the `;` into the `{}` after each instruction

Answer (score 30):

One way to check if a variable is empty is:

```
if [ "$var" = "" ]; then
    # $var is empty
fi
```

Another, shorter alternative is this:

```
[ "$var" ] || # var is empty
```

Comment: The `x"$var" = x` trick is only relevant for ancient, buggy versions of the Bourne shell. `[ "$var" = "" ]` is sufficient today.

Answer (score 11):

In bash you can use `set -u` which causes bash to exit on failed parameter expansion.

From bash man (section about `set` builtin):

> -u
>   Treat unset variables and parameters other than the special parameters "@" and "*" as an error when performing parameter
>   expansion. If expansion is attempted on an unset variable or
>   parameter, the shell prints an error message, and, if not interactive,
>   exits with a non-zero status.

For more information I recommend this article: 
http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/

Comment: -u only detects when a variable is unset not when it is empty

Answer (score 4):

You can use a short form:

```
FNAME="$I_IDOCMD5"
: ${FNAME:="$I_LEGALMD5"}
: ${FNAME:="$I_ZIPMD5"}
: ${FNAME:?"Usage: $0 filename"}
```

In this case the script will exit if neither of the `I_...` variables is declared, printing an error message prepended with the shell script line that triggered the message.

See more on this in [abs-guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) (search for «Example 10-7»).

Answer (score 3):

First test only this (just to narrow it down):

```
if [ -z "$I_IDOCMD5" ] || [ -z "$I_LEGALMD5" ] || [ -z "$I_ZIPMD5" ]
then
    echo "one is missing"
else
    echo "everything OK"
fi

echo "\"$I_IDOCMD5\""
echo "\"$I_LEGALMD5\""
echo "\"$I_ZIPMD5\""
```

Comment: On it is own seems to work.. but in the real script it is somehow executing both the end and the else
If i take the test above it would display "one is missing" BUT also display "everything OK"

Comment: Maybe because your last `if` block is not closed by a `fi` ? add an extra `fi`to the end.  Hint: expand your indentation a bit.

Comment: I admit that I ran you script (with simulated variables) and it baild out on an error. I corrected it and it did OK.

Answer (score 0):

*"if the variable is empty it means there is no file on the sftp server"*

If there is no file on the sftp server, *is* the variable then *really* empty ?

No hidden spaces or anything like that ? or the number zero (which counts as non-empty) ?

Comment: Hello, it is empty, I have stripped all espaces.. but also now that you mention it. the value can be 0... if the value is 0 (integer 0 or it is empty ( no hidden spaces)

Comment: integer 0 would fail the -z test if interpreted as string (string is not empty). You could test it with the code mentioned in the other answer.